# Keystroke logging in virtual machine with soft keyboard

Tags: keyloggers

In conjunction with this question:

[Keystroke logging and virtual machines](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109709/keystroke-logging-and-virtual-machines)

I'd like to ask if for example, while using the VM, could the keylogger (keylogger inside host) still log if I was using a virtual (soft) keyboard?

[image: screenshot]

Other info:

This screenshot was from an Android emulator with soft keyboard settings turned on.

Comment: potentially relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172135/are-virtual-keyboards-not-necessary-anymore-to-protect-against-keyloggers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some keyloggers capture inputs to virtual keyboards by taking screenshots whenever the mouse clicks. This is still effective if the host has a keylogger and the guest VM is using a virtual keyboard.

The host OS receives the click from the mouse and then passes that event on to the VM. The keylogger on the host could take a screenshot at that time.

Screenshots are just one way of capturing inputs to keyloggers, but it's the example you are looking for.

Comment: okay got it I understand, so having a virtual keyboard via vmware doesn't help at all. thank you

Comment: @Ghost: I wouldn't say they don't help at all, but they are certainly not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Screen session otherwise known as video capture software recording the entire screen would also be a simply way of thwarting a virtual keyboard. Ever see a video session captured and replayed on YouTube or similar? Pretty straight forward.

Now, do such while running inconspicuously in the background with no one noticing may prove problematic but certainly should be considered.

Comment: that's no longer a "keystroke logger" though